# Territory Management

Tags: administration, territory-management

when do you use territory management? Also what is my role a admin far as enabling this  feature is concerned? do i just enable and set it up or do i have to train them etc? are there any drawbacks to this feature?

do admins just mostly enable stuff with respects to features and capabilities in sf. how do you train the user to use the features in sf. how time consuming is it etc?

in general every time you enable something there are so many things to consider so how do you manage all of that? there are so many warning notices in documentation and things to remember etc.

how do you notify users of changes you made etc.

i apologize for the rookie questions. i ma new to IT and SF.

Comment: Please go through documentation first or try to google it. I see that you don't know anything about salesforce but you are directly jumping into  concepts of security.

Comment: Welcome to salesforce.stackexchange user6996 (maybe a real username is a good idea?) - within this community we try to focus on specific questions with re-usable answers that can help others in the future. Broad opinion prone questions and answers are therefore rather discouraged. For many things the community can provide great answers, but if you're an admin for a company it may also be wise to team up with experienced professionals from a local salesforce partner.

Answer (score 2):

Territory management basically related to sharing model of an organization. We can say it is a structure based sharing. It allow sharing of information according to geographical condition or some specific type of accounts which are categorised by some fields.

Territory management allow us to manage complex sharing between accounts which have some similarity in between. It expands the sharing between same territory Accounts.

There can be several things need to be consider when enabling Territory management:

- First thing is it cannot be disabled
- It is mostly used where org wide access is set to private and we need to provide some access to specific group of accounts according to their territory. For ex: Forecasting.
- Territory affects Contacts, Account, Opportunity, Case and all custom object which have master-detail relationship with account. So sharing to these object should be considered.
- If there are some requirement of development on Territory object then it must be known that territory is a **Setup Object**
- By enabling territory all sharing of accounts done according to the territory and their hierarchy.
- Forecasting based on territory can be done when enabled.

In summary, territory account organise a complex sharing between accounts of different geographical conditions and saves you from lot of headache of manually setting up sharing for organization having thousands of users and have org wide private sharing for objects.
Territory management is a complex and powerful feature to use.

Users are not require for training but Salesforce admin must aware of what he is going to do and what impacts will be on Users using the feature. Also managers like Sales Manager, Forecast manager etc must aware of the change so they can now the new sharing expansion to users in their hierarchy.